# How do you limit access to a web API?

Tags: api, authentication, cordova, whatsapp

How do companies like WhatsApp protect their API's from 3rd party access?

In other words, how do they prevent someone from making requests to whats.app.server.address and process the response?

I want to make a PhoneGap based chat application, but I don't want it accessible to anyone over the web.. I want them to have to use my PhoneGap client.  Is this possible?

My thinking is that if I use some kind of api-key it will have to be put in the js file that will later send requests to my server.. but this is public, so anyone could view source and start using my api-key in the same way..

My feeling is that I'm not thinking about this correctly, and I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Are you looking for `OAUTH2`? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749